# How to add/create roles using commands in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so I'm trying to have a user look at a list of potential "roles", and based on what the user selects, (whether or not the role exists at the moment or not) the bot will either add the role to the user, or create a new role to add to the user. At the moment, I keep getting an error saying name "message" is not defined, but I'm not really sure what to do.

Here is my code

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def classes():
class_list = ["English", "Math", "Science", "History", "Geography", "French","Technology", "Comp_Sci", "Business", "Music", "Art"]
entered_class = message.content
role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=entered_class)
roles = ["470082568163950612", "470082563696754708"]
if role is None:
    await client.create_role(name=entered_class, mentionable=True)
    await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
    msg = 'Successfully created and added role{0.author.mention}'.format(message)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
if role is True:
    await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

And heres my imports

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get
from discord.utils import find
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

TOKEN = 'NDcwMDYwMDc1MjgxODA5NDEw.DjQyZQ.j-YlOu5mZnDjpeUj32Nbc7wfbbs'


client = Bot(command_prefix = "Wood!")
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The error message `name "message" is not defined` is telling you that you're trying to access a variable called "message" that doesn't exist.

Looking at your code, it seems to be here:

```
async def classes():
    class_list = ["English", "Math", "Science", "History", "Geography", "French","Technology", "Comp_Sci", "Business", "Music", "Art"]
    entered_class = HERE ---> message <--- .content
```

What you need to is this:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def classes(ctx): # note that we add a `ctx` argument here
    class_list = ["English", "Math", "Science", "History", "Geography", "French","Technology", "Comp_Sci", "Business", "Music", "Art"]
    entered_class = ctx.message.content # we get the message from the context here
```

But actually, that's probably not what you want, since it will contain the command name and prefix as well as the argument. You're using the commands extension for discord.py, so you will probably prefer to do it like this:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def classes(ctx, arg): # commands extension gets the argument for you!
```

and then just use the value of the `arg` variable.

On a separate note, **NEVER, EVER** share your bot token with anyone. Go back to the discord page and regenerate it **now**. This is because with that token, **anyone** who sees it can access your bot and make it do anything.